# Converting date from one timezone to other timezone using ISO date string

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, iso

I want to convert a date(`10/14/2022 8:04 PM`) from `America/New_York` timezone
to `Asia/Tokyo`'timezone as shown below.
I have used ISO format with 'Asia/Tokyo' timezone.
But I am getting one hour less after conversion
because `08:04:00 p.m. Friday October 14, 2022 in America/New_York`
converts to `09:04:00 a.m. Saturday October 15, 2022 in Asia/Tokyo.`

Even for other timeZone I have also tried but problem is same.
Please help me to understand the problem in this code

```js
let d = new Date('2022-10-14T20:04:00.000+09:00')

console.log(
  d.toLocaleString('ko-KR', {
    timeZone:'Asia/Tokyo', 
    hour12:false
  })
);
```

Result is: `2022. 10. 14. 20시 4분 0초`

Comment: Both the image you attached and the text result have the same time as your input.  Where is the hour off?  Neither show any conversion from New York time either.

Comment: Images removed, date is in ISO format.

Comment: there is no conversion to perform. all machines use all the same zero time zone regardless of their location on the planet. and they all synchronize with servers also based on a zero time zone.

What you are looking for is not a conversion but a display with times zones of your choice, and this is precisely what the method you use to change the default TZ value of the host machine offers

Comment: @MisterJojo I have updated the question for better understanding, but have you tried it once?

Comment: The question is still unclear, so it's difficult to answer.  The paragraph shows a non-ISO format without any time zone information, while the code just below it shows an ISO format with `+09:00`, which is already the correct offset for Tokyo.  Those two are inconsistent.  Please edit your question to show *exactly* the code that reproduces the issue, including the exact input and output.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint question updated.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still unclear.  Where does New York come in to your code?  Is it *actually* `"America/New_York"` as a string-based time zone identifier somewhere in your code?  Or do you just mean that your local time zone is New York time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New York time zone is **-4 hours** (not +9hours) as yours.
see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

In your case of -- `10/14/2022 8:04 PM` at America/New_York:

```js
let dateUTC = new Date('2022-10-14T20:04:00.000-04:00') 

console.log('Verify America/New_York date value: (where timeZone is -4 hours according DST)')
console.log( 'America/New_York -->', dateUTC.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York', hour12:true }) )


console.log( '\nAsia/Tokyo -->', dateUTC.toLocaleString('ko-KR', { timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo', hour12:false }) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

> As you can see, there is no conversion to do. Just set the correct date value indicating its original timezone offset (take care of possible daylight saving time [DST]).
> Then just display your date/time with the local values you want.

Comment: I tried this solution already @Mister Jojo before posting it here, but don't know why it was not working for me at that time. I am shocked and also happy. Thanks.