# Set hour for initial timezone of the date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

If I receive the following date string on the server which has a timezone of `+03:00`

```
2022-10-24T00:00:00+05:00
```

I want to set the hour to something fixed, 8 A.M. let's say, so the result would be

```
2022-10-24T08:00:00+05:00
```

which would translate to `2022-10-24T06:00:00+03:00` according the timezone of the server.

How can I achieve this with the Date object or moment, without modifying the string directly? My problem is that if I try to set the hour after creating a date/moment object that will set the hour for the already converted to the server timezone date (`2022-10-24T08:00:00+03:00`).

Comment: there is nothing to change anywhere. your original string value should be used without change. it is valid for any server on the planet.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74101108/converting-date-from-one-timezone-to-other-timezone-using-iso-date-string/74102753#74102753

Comment: just load the date into utc timezone, set the time to 8 and then apply the +3 timezone format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) for this purpose, [`moment.js is not recommended for new projects.`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

It's easy to do with the [`DateTime.fromISO()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromiso) method, setting the `setZone` parameter to true and passing in the original timestamp.

If we log the date now we should see:

```
2022-10-24T00:00:00.000+05:00
```

We can then use the [`set()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeset) method to set the hour to 8.

If we log the date now we should see (as expected):

```
2022-10-24T08:00:00.000+05:00
```

We can then use [`DateTime.toLocal()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetolocal) to return to the local or server timezone.

If we log the date now we should see:

```
2022-10-24T06:00:00.000+03:00
```

(as long as we're in a timezone that's currently UTC+03:00)

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon; 

let dt = DateTime.fromISO('2022-10-24T00:00:00+05:00', { setZone: true });

console.log('Initial date:'.padEnd(24), dt.toString());

dt = dt.set({ hour: 8 });

console.log('After setting hour:'.padEnd(24), dt.toString());
console.log('After setting to local:'.padEnd(24), dt.toLocal().toString() );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-6ZJuab/UnRq1muTChgrVxJhSgygmL2GMLVmSJN7pcBEqJ1dWPbqN9CiZ6U3HrcApTIJsLnMgXYBYgtVkJ8fWiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```